# google map application passing latitude and longitude so that the user can then navigate to the place

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework

I am a new to Ionic. I have done some google search but I am still a bit confused.

From my android Ionic app I would like to launch the google map application passing latitude and longitude so that the user can then navigate to the place.

Is is possible? Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>

   <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="main">
   <div ui-view>
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Login App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <div>
            </div>
                <div class="list list-inset">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.email">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="postLogin()">Login</button>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
}).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'index.html',
                controller: 'main'
            })
            .state('userPositionInMap', {
                url: '/userPositionInMap',
                templateUrl: 'map.html',
                controller: 'MapController'
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });



app.controller('main', function ($scope,$http,$stateParams,$ionicPopup,$location) 
{ 

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.postLogin = function ()
    {

        var data = 
        {
                email: $scope.data.email,
                password: $scope.data.password,
                latitude,
                langitude
        };


        $http.post("http://localhost/authproject/public/api/auth/login", data)
        .then(
           function(response){
             // success callback
             console.log('success');
             data.latitude=response.latitude;
             data.langitude=response.langitude;
             $location.path("/userPositionInMap");


           }, 
           function(response){
             // failure callback
             console.log('error');
             var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });

           }
        );

    }

});



app.controller('MapController', function ($scope,$stateParams) 
{ 


});
```

map.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsiDiIzQjg7U9JYPDVl8hnfZ7MwDcHDHg&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<script>
    function initMap() {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 48.85661400000001 , lng: 2.3522220000000177 });

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: 48.85661400000001 , lng: 2.3522220000000177 },
                    zoom: 15
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: ""
                });

                //var input = document.getElementById('address');
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

                var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(myLatlng);
                autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    //anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
                });

                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {

                    marker.setVisible(false);
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (place != undefined) {
                        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
                        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
                        console.log(place.geometry.location.toString());
                        $('#lat').val(lat);
                        $('#lng').val(lng);
                    }
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }

                    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(16);
                    }
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                });
            }
</script>
<ion-view view-title="Map">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Map</div>
      <div class="item item-body">

      <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: No one really wants to traipse through reams of code. See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code first. You need to demonstrate what you understand and what you've tried first.

Comment: I want to do a login application, when I click a login button i would pass to the page map with passing latitude and longitude of user

Comment: What is the point of that exactly? Some additional form of authentication? Pass it to what? You need to elaborate a bit more I think (in the question).

Comment: I would to know how i retrieves langitude and latitude from database and how to pass those parameters to my map

Comment: I see, well that makes more sense now. I can't really help I'm not familiar with ionic or angular. PS: don't you mean longitude rather than langitude?

Answer (score 0):

I have a rough idea of what you are tying to achieve. You can wrap your code for the map in a directive, then via the link function you can access $rootScope which you can use to hold the lat and lng from the database. Here is the doc for directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Angular-maps : https://angular-maps.com/

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: [`
    agm-map {
      height: 300px;
    }
  `],
  template: `
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-map>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
}
```